# Can I make Textmate completions ignore capitalisation?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate, textmatebundles

I've used `Textmate` for a couple of years, but for Objective-C I'm finding that Xcode is easier. One of the reasons I like Xcode is that I can type "nsui" and it will suggest NSUInteger for me. If I want the same thing in Textmate, I have to type "NSUI" since the start of the suggestion I want is all capitalised. Textmate won't match the start of the completion I want if the capitalisation is different. I love Textmate, but my pinky is getting tired of holding down shift all the time.

I'm guessing that the completions in Textmate come from the "Completions: Cocoa" in the bundle. Is there a way to turn off the capitalisation sensitivity in Textmate so that I can type either "nsui" or "NSUI" and get an "NSUInteger" suggestion?

---

**Edit:**

It looks like it's not possible. I went through the completions support yesterday, and it's possible to get the list of completions from a script (I wrote a script to pull possible completions from the dict/words file) but textmate always seems to compare the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think TextMate is that sophisticated. In the bundle editor you can create a snippet that inserts NSUInteger and has a tab trigger "nsui". If you want it to work for "NSUI" as well, then duplicate the snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably end up doing this.